# Meaning of "retiring" in "free admission with retiring donations"

Tags: phrase-meaning

We recently attended a concert in a protestant church in England that was advertised as "free admission with retiring donations". The concert was indeed free with a voluntary (optional) donation.

What is the meaning of *retiring* in this context?

Googling without quotes gives results for people retiring from work, which is obviously not meant here, and googling with quotes returned similar events being advertised as such.

Comment: Where (in the world) was the concert?

Comment: Was the concert given in aid of someone's retirement?

Comment: There are many examples shown in a Google search for << "retiring collection" + meaning >>. A collection to which people donate on leaving the room or building etc. 'Valedictory' is unidiomatic here.

Comment: _Retiring collection_ is  in common use in the UK (in the sense given by D.J. Clayworth).

Comment: This should not have been closed. It's a good question with a possible answer.

Comment: [Oxford Languages (courtesy of Google)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22retiring+collection%22+%2B+meaning+%3E%3E&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=%22retiring+collection%22+%2B+meaning+%3E%3E&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30j0i390i650l3.1671j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) provides: << 
**retiring collection**  [noun]
a collection of donations from people as they leave an event, typically for a charity or to cover the expenses of performers or speakers at the event itself. >> The usual collocation (70x as many hits as for "retiring donations" in a Google search).

Comment: Concert was in a protestent church in England,  noone was retiring, it was just some community Sunday music

Answer (score 34, accepted):

"Retiring donations" (more commonly "retiring collection") means you will be asked for donations on your way out - [using "retire" in the sense of "to leave a room or group of people"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/retire).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148573/discussion-on-answer-by-djclayworth-meaning-of-retiring-in-free-admission-wit); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

We use the term in Baptist circles to indicate, as previously stated, an offering that will be taken up at the end of the service. This would usually be for a cause outside of our church. Maybe we will have heard abut the work of a charity during the service, and we will take up 'a retiring offering' as we leave the service, to benefit that charity.